# android https - self signed server certificate - exception

Tags: android, ssl

Referred links:

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa
http://randomizedsort.blogspot.com/2010/09/step-to-step-guide-to-programming.html

I have the following code for connecting to server with self-signed certificate (I use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15531475/682869) for the keystore part) :

```
 try
 {
   final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
   final InputStream inputStream = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certs);
   ks.load(inputStream, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.store_pass).toCharArray());
   inputStream.close();

   TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
   tmf.init(ks);

   SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
   context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

   URL url = new URL("https://www.mywebsite.com/");
   HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
   InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // the toast appear empty (described in question)
 }
```

If I use my website's name as :

```
 http://www.mywebsite.com
```

then in my surrounding try catch, an exception is thrown :

```
 com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl 
 cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

If I use :

```
 https://www.mywebsite.com
```

then I still get an exception, but due to some reason, the Exception object 'e' in `catch(Exception e)` has empty message (its not null), so I can't figure out the exception.

If I try to use :

```
 Log.d("TEST", e.getMessage());
```

then I get:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Can some one point out what I am doing wrong ?

**Edit:**

Here's the output of e.printStackTrace()

```
D/TEST﹕ e.printStackTrace() :
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.authmobile.app.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:90)
06-18 14:20:17.493      W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-18 14:20:17.497      W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-18 14:20:17.497      W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-18 14:20:17.497      W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-18 14:20:17.497      W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-18 14:20:17.497      W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-18 14:20:17.497      W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 14:20:17.497      W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-18 14:20:17.497      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-18 14:20:17.497      W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-18 14:20:17.497      W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There is no `catch(Exception e)` in your code shown above.

Comment: @CommonsWare : added, sorry about that.

Comment: Is there anything else in LogCat, such as a stack trace logged by something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare Edited the exception part (added log part as well).

Comment: try e.printStackTrace() instead.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237080/exception-getmessage-is-null

Comment: No, I meant simply looking at LogCat, to see if something else logged a stack trace or other message before it threw the poorly-crafted message-less `Exception`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've edited the output of e.printStackTrace in the catch block.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: @CommonsWare One question of my approach, since I am creating a custom keystore and providing my server's pem file in my app, is this certificate pinning for SSL ?

Comment: More or less. The term "certificate pinning" is not usually used with respect to self-signed certificates. Effectively, checking the validity of a self-signed certificate accomplishes what certificate pinning would.

Comment: @CommonsWare The keystore steps at the start of my sample code .. does it just trust the server certificate without validating it ? Could you point to some web link on how to check the validity of the certificate ? (I am using the step # 3 in the linked keystore answer). Thanks for all your help !

Comment: There is no means to validate whether the file in your app is the actual keystore. The assumption is that your app is not tampered with, and that you are validating the certificate served by the *server* compared against the keystore baked into your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I asked a more concrete question of my situation here, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException.  Newer versions of Android do not allow you to perform network tasks in the same thread as the UI, as they can cause your app to lock up and go non-responsive.  Move your network operation to an AsyncTask.  See the Android training doc for [Connecting to the Network](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).